# Half Screen White on Second Montior While Connected to HDMI Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display

Yesterday I connected an Asus External monitor to my laptop dualbooting Ubuntu and Windows 11, it worked perfectly with windows but when I use it in Ubuntu, it shows something like this in the image:

[image: image of my monitor]

I tried a lot of stuff like changing drivers from Additional drivers, using Ubuntu on Xorg, changing resolutions from Display Setting.
Here is what Xrandr outputs:

````
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 470mm x 260mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     60.08*+
   1440x1080     60.05  
   1400x1050     60.05  
   1280x1024     60.03  
   1280x960      60.09  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       60.00  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     60.10  
   1440x900      60.03  
   1280x800      59.99  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      60.07  
   1368x768      60.06  
   1280x720      60.06  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77    ```

What should I be doing or What am I doing wrong?
````

Comment: Exactly same issue. Video card RTX 3070. I can even add - it happened after Ubuntu update of bunch of software. But booting with old kernel didnt help